# The floating point issue and how to overcome it

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to calculate quite correctly the elevation between different points. This means they should be as correct as possible. Sadly I have however done my complete script in floating numbers. Now at the final elevation calculation I get wrong height informations. I read already a lot about the floating issue, but sadly I cannot find any way to overcome it. Some say I should round my floating number up and then play with it, others say that one should use decimal system. Sadly there is not really a source where I can find the best solution which suits my problem best.

My elevation values (variable ListOfValues) are:

```
195,1850 
195,1550 
195,1625 
195,1400 
195,1350 
195,0925 
195,1050 
195,0800 
195,0825 
195,0625 
195,0650 
195,0350 
195,0425
```

Here is my code:

```
for i in range(0, len(ListOfValues)-1):
        Elevation = Elevation + abs(ListOfValues[i] - ListOfValues[i+1])
    for i in range(0, len(ListOfValues)-2):
        if ListOfValues[i]<ListOfValues[i+1]:
            ElevationUpwards=ElevationUpwards+(ListOfValues[i+1] - ListOfValues[i])

        if ListOfValues[i]>ListOfValues[i+1]:
            ElevationDownwards=ElevationDownwards+(ListOfValues[i] - ListOfValues[i+1])
```

Instead of getting the upwards elevation value of `0,0325`, I get through Python `0.024999999999977263`. The difference is too big for my means.
Find below the calculations of Python:

```
195.185-195.155=0.030000000000001137
195.1625-195.155=0.007499999999993179
195.1625-195.14=0.052500000000009095
195.14-195.135=0.05750000000000455
195.135-195.0925=0.09999999999999432
195.105-195.0925=0.01999999999998181
195.105-195.08=0.12499999999997158
195.0825-195.08=0.022499999999979536
195.0825-195.0625=0.1449999999999818
195.065-195.0625=0.024999999999977263
195.065-195.035=0.17499999999998295
```

What would you suggest to come as close as possible to the "real" elevation value?

---

Edit:
While it is suggested to use the decimal way, I tried this one. My code is now:

```
Elevation=Decimal(0.0)
ElevationUpwards=Decimal(0.0)
ElevationDownwards=Decimal(0.0)
for i in range(0, len(ListOfValues)-1):
        Elevation = Elevation + abs(Decimal(ListOfValues[i]) - Decimal(ListOfValues[i+1]))
for i in range(0, len(ListOfValues)-1):
        if ListOfValues[i]<ListOfValues[i+1]:
            ElevationUpwards=ElevationUpwards+(Decimal(ListOfValues[i+1]) - Decimal(ListOfValues[i]))

        if ListOfValues[i]>ListOfValues[i+1]:
            ElevationDownwards=ElevationDownwards+(Decimal(ListOfValues[i]) - Decimal(ListOfValues[i+1]))
```

The result of this code is now again: `0.03249999999997044142219237984`
Am I doing something totally wrong?

Comment: stop using floats? theres alternatives available like [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) and [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/fractions.html).

Comment: Such a large error after just a bunch of additions/substractions with numbers having small differences in magnitude can't be caused by rounding problems with floats. Check your algorithm.

Comment: I added the calculation above to the first post.

Comment: My answer shows that you've still got `len(ListOfValues)-2` instead of `len(ListOfValues)-1` in your update that uses `Decimal`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to copy the right code, but I fixed it now. But I still get the approximation instead of the "real" value.

Comment: I don't see the difference. You get the value you are looking for. If you literally want 0.0325 then see the update to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code you meant to write.

It would have been good if you could have posted this code in the first place.

```
ListOfValues = [195.1850,
195.1550,
195.1625,
195.1400,
195.1350,
195.0925,
195.1050,
195.0800,
195.0825,
195.0625,
195.0650,
195.0350,
195.0425]

Elevation = 0             # Elevation is not used after the loops
ElevationUpwards = 0
ElevationDownwards = 0    # ElevationDownwards is not used after the loops

for i in range(0, len(ListOfValues)-1):
    Elevation = Elevation + abs(ListOfValues[i] - ListOfValues[i+1])

for i in range(0, len(ListOfValues)-1):  # Changed this to -1 instead of -2 as posted
    if ListOfValues[i]<ListOfValues[i+1]:
        ElevationUpwards=ElevationUpwards+(ListOfValues[i+1] - ListOfValues[i])

    if ListOfValues[i]>ListOfValues[i+1]:
        ElevationDownwards=ElevationDownwards+(ListOfValues[i] - ListOfValues[i+1])

print(ElevationUpwards)
```

Output:

```
0.03249999999997044
```

This seems to be the value you are looking for.

Your code, as written but with proper indentation, produced the erroneous `0.0245` value.

**Update:**

You can always fix your values before the calculation and correct the result afterwards:

```
ListOfValues=[int(v*10000) for v in ListOfValues]
# Then do the calculations
print(ElevationUpwards/10000)
```

Output:

```
0.0325
```